# What are the Best practices to end the websphere MQ Queue Manager?

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

Whenever we try to restart my queue managers in MQ server, some processes are listening eventhough we are ending the QM with`endmqm <QM> and endmqm -i <QM>`. Because of these processes which are listening to that ended QM, we are unable to start the QM.

Can anybody suggest the best practice to kill the processes automatically while ending the QM?

Answer (score 0):

What version of MQ are you running?  i.e. issue the dspmqver command

Have you applied the latest FixPack?

The queue manager should shutdown without any issue.  Do your applications use the *_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING options for MQOPEN, MQGET & MQPUT calls?  This is clearly documented in IBM's MQ Best Practices.  If applications are not using the MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING option for MQGET with wait then the application will hold the MCA from shutting down.

Comment: MQ Ver : 7.0.1.8. Not sure how the applications are connected